# Are there any good and free devexpress data grid alternatives for winforms?

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, datagrid, devexpress

Are there any good free alternatives to DevExpress data grids (WinForms)?

I am looking for WinForms Data Grid and Data Editor Controls.
Some good ones where you can sort and group by columns and edit data inside the grid.

Comment: Most people use the `DataGridView` control. It supports all that, and since it's included with WinForms, it's completely free.

Answer (score 14):

If the built in DataGridView control is not good enough, here are some alternatives:

- http://sourcegrid.codeplex.com/
- http://www.codeproject.com/KB/user-controls/EditableGridView.aspx
- http://www.codeproject.com/KB/grid/OutlookGrid.aspx

Answer (score 3):

Late to the party but I've just from SyncFusion which is free for <$1M companies. Their grid looks pretty good [High Performance WinForms DataGrid Control](https://www.syncfusion.com/winforms-ui-controls/datagrid)

Note you have to claim a free [community license](https://www.syncfusion.com/products/communitylicense) - and I have no affiliation with these

Answer (score 0):

I spot another free .NET Grid called MegaGrid .NET WinForms Control, and you can check out the link http://www.mw6tech.com/megagrid/net/megagrid.html

Comment: This package isn't free though.  It has a trial version.  It costs $499 for 1 dev. license.