# collecting textbox text with checkboxlist item using vb.net

Tags: vb.net, textbox, checkboxlist

am building a task management system using vb.net. How to set a textbox field beside each checkboxlist so when the user tick the checkbox he can comment too for this item and submit the whole finished tasks ?  below is my code

```
 Sub GetGroups()
        cblGroups.DataSource = Task.Components.Tasks.GetAllTasks
        cblGroups.DataTextField = "TaskName"
        cblGroups.DataValueField = "ID"
        cblGroups.DataBind()


    End Sub


  For Each item As ListItem In cblGroups.Items
            If item.Selected Then

'reading each item value

End if
```

Next

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Aside: `.Selected` and `SelectedItems` is not the same thing as `CheckedItems`. if you are wanting to process the checked items, iterated the `CheckedItems` or `CheckedIndices` collection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should be using a DataGridView instead. In there you can have a checkbox column and a textbox column, also a new row placeholder to put new tasks. If you don't like DataGridView, you can use [alternatives](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6008509/897326).

Your other option would be to maintain a list of CheckBox controls and their TextBox pairs, essentially doing data grid's job. You are okay at first, but then you may need scrolling etc., so why not use a built-in control, where such issues are already solved out of the box.

Comment: I prefer to use it withour dridview, can we manage to put textbox beside each checkbox item and read the value of the text ?

Comment: @Dan: You can do everything - time is the only concern. Coding this home-made data grid is out of scope, please ask a concrete question about implementation, if you have one.

Comment: whats the built-in control you have suggested ?

Comment: @Dan: [DataGridView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.windows.forms.datagridview).

Answer (score 0):

```
    'Check through each of the items
    For Each item As ListItem In cblGroups.Items
        'If this particular item is checked
        If item.Selected = True Then
            'Dynamically create a HTML Textbox
            item.Text = [String].Format("{0}<input id=""TextBox{0}"" name=""TextBox{0}"" / >", item.Text)
        Else
            'Otherwise simply store the normal value
            item.Text = [String].Format("{0}", item.Text)
        End If
    Next
```

Comment: Try This That Create Dynamic HTML TextBox in textfield of ListItem